# How to get persisted data(using javascript) in java class?

Tags: android, cordova, persistence, jstorage

I am developing a cordova application for android.I am persisted some data using jStorage from my javascript.I want to start a service using native code.Is it possible to get the persisted data in my java class. If yes how can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you will need to write your own plugin and pass your persistent data to the native class. you can simply do that by passing the data as arguments in the `cordova.exec`-method.

read http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide for further instructions on plugin development.